# Tor Browser needs to be started twice

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, windows, startup

About 85% of the time, when I start Tor Browser, I get the "Something Went Wrong!" page and have to try a second time.  Apparently, some initialization isn't finishing before the browser window shows up, but the error screen isn't very helpful in identifying exactly what.  I think this started with the 9.5 series, but I don't remember any more specifically than "it's been a few months".  Anyone here know what's causing this, or how I can find out?

Comment: If you don't find an answer, you may want to make an issue at https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/applications/tor-browser/-/issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the tor service that is running with the browser. Make sure that any anti-virus or anti-malware on your computer whitelists Tor Browser. If that doesn't fix it, uninstall and then reinstall it.